# AuthorizationManager error when running ANY Powershell script (Invalid class also)

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell

One of our Win Server 2008R2 crashed today, then after restarting it, I cannot run any Powershell script on it, I get the error "AuthorizationManager check failed." When I run the `Get-ExecutionPolicy` cmdlet, I got another error:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy : Invalid class
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ Get-ExecutionPolicy
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ExecutionPolicy], ManagementException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.ManagementException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetExecutionPolicyCommand
```

I checked the services, everything seems to be ok and running. Tried restarting the server again, the problem persists. I guess something got corrupted when it crashed. Anyone has seen this?

Comment: New to me.  You tried reinstalling or repairing WMF?

Comment: I tried reinstalling but the uninstallation failed. I think I got it working, I admit it's not elegant. I got many logs about GPO failing because WMI was not right, so I checked the system32\wbem\repository folder, there was a Corrupted.rec file, and the files sizes were way too small. I have a second server with the exact same roles, apps and configuration, so for the sake of testing I copied all the files  from this second server and put in the problematic one (backed up first). Restarted the Wmi service, powershell scripts started working immediately, no erros on Get-ExecutionPolicy.

Comment: Checked the repository with winmgmt /verifyrepository and it's consistent. I don't think its the best way to solve this, but it's what I got by now, I'll keep monitoring.

Comment: Oh, yeah, WMI corruption.  That happens... well, often enough that it's one of the first things I check when a Windows box starts acting strange.  Props on the novel way you fixed it, but for future reference, a better/more standard/supported way of doing it is to rebuild the WMI repository.  [The accepted answer here has detailed instructions on how to do that](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8ed26d46-9994-4052-a307-5b071805aea8/wmi-corrupt-how-to-reinstallrepair).

Comment: Thanks, I'll certainly try that method if I bump again with a situation of WMI corruption in the future.